# The geometric meaning of isotropy in Kahler manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I saw the isotropy of Kahler manifold below:

[image]

I wonder if there is a geometric motivation for this definition, is there any connection with the definition of the isotropy in mapping class group?

Comment: I think it just refers to this linear algebra definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form